# Adjusting font style for a RichTextBox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, fonts, richtextbox, adjustment

I'm having trouble adjusting the font style in a RichTextBox and I've seen a few different approaches that talk about single attributes (like toggling bold on and off)... but I'm trying to make it so that my font class can adjust *any* attribute (bold, italic, underline).

I realize that Font.Style is a set of Boolean flags (a bitfield?)... but I'm not sure how to handle the attributes all at once.

Here is the troublesome code:

```
Public Sub ModifyFontStyle(Optional ByVal Plain As Object = Nothing, Optional ByVal Bold As Object = Nothing, _
                           Optional ByVal Italics As Object = Nothing, Optional ByVal Underlined As Object = Nothing)
    Dim newFontStyle As System.Drawing.FontStyle


    If Plain Then
        newFontStyle = Drawing.FontStyle.Regular
        GivenFont = New Drawing.Font(GivenFont.FontFamily, GivenFont.Size, newFontStyle)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Bold IsNot Nothing Then
        If Bold Then
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style + Drawing.FontStyle.Bold
        Else
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style - Drawing.FontStyle.Bold
        End If
    End If


    If Italics IsNot Nothing Then
        If Italics Then
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style + Drawing.FontStyle.Italic
        Else
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style - Drawing.FontStyle.Italic
        End If
    End If

    If Underlined IsNot Nothing Then
        If Underlined Then
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style + Drawing.FontStyle.Underline
        Else
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style - Drawing.FontStyle.Underline
        End If
    End If

    GivenFont = New Drawing.Font(GivenFont.FontFamily, GivenFont.Size, newFontStyle)

End Sub
```

And here is the eventual trouble with this code:

- I toggle bold (to true) - the text goes bold.
- I toggle underlined - the text is now bold and underlined.
- I toggle italics - the text is now bold, underlined, and in italics.
- I toggle bold again (to false) - the text is now strikethrough.

What is happening to the font? The text should be underlined and in italics not strikethrough...

Is this a logic error or a simple misunderstanding on my part?

Well, thank you for your time, I'll keep tinkering around with it until it is working or I get an answer that works,

Comment: I figured out what I need to do: check the specific attribute I'm adjusting and stop it from being added to the font style more than once. I'll post the answer to this question in a little while.

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong operators.  They are indeed similar to bit flags, the enum has the [Flags] attribute.  You'll need to use the Or operator to turn a style on and the And operator to turn a style off.  Like this:

```
    Dim style = Me.Font.Style
    '--- turn bold on
    style = style Or FontStyle.Bold
    '--- turn bold off
    style = style And Not FontStyle.Bold
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've got it. I've gotten it to work successfully.

```
Public Sub ModifyFontStyle(Optional ByVal Plain As Object = Nothing, Optional ByVal Bold As Object = Nothing, _
                           Optional ByVal Italics As Object = Nothing, Optional ByVal Underlined As Object = Nothing)
    Dim newFontStyle As System.Drawing.FontStyle


    If Plain Then
        newFontStyle = Drawing.FontStyle.Regular
        GivenFont = New Drawing.Font(GivenFont.FontFamily, GivenFont.Size, newFontStyle)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Bold IsNot Nothing Then
        If Bold And Not GivenFont.Bold Then
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style + Drawing.FontStyle.Bold
        Else
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style - Drawing.FontStyle.Bold
        End If
    End If


    If Italics IsNot Nothing Then
        If Italics And Not GivenFont.Italic Then
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style + Drawing.FontStyle.Italic
        Else
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style - Drawing.FontStyle.Italic
        End If
    End If

    If Underlined IsNot Nothing Then
        If Underlined And Not GivenFont.Underline Then
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style + Drawing.FontStyle.Underline
        Else
            newFontStyle = GivenFont.Style - Drawing.FontStyle.Underline
        End If
    End If

    GivenFont = New Drawing.Font(GivenFont.FontFamily, GivenFont.Size, newFontStyle)

End Sub
```

Thanks for your time!